# Simplify — is this simplest result Mathematica can provide?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex, assumptions

I have a question about `Simplify`: When I do a simplification the returned result is not as simple as I want. When I ask for the Norm of an complex expression, *Mathematica* just returns `Norm[expr]`.

I don't know how to make it simpler, is this the final form that Mathematica can give?

```
Simplify[Conjugate[h^4 k^2 + 2 I h^2 k m V + (-1 + E^(2 I k l)) m^2 V^2], 
  {k, V, m, h, l} ∈ Reals]
```

When evaluating the above code, Mathematica just returns `Conjugate[...]`, but what I need is a form without `Conjugate` in the front, just replace $i$ to $-i$ as usual math calculation.

Comment: You've seen `ComplexExpand[]`?

Comment: Next time I will try this with complex functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[
       Conjugate[(-1 + E^(2 I k l)) m^2 V^2 + 2 I k m V \[HBar]^2 + 
              k^2 \[HBar]^4], {k, V, m, \[HBar], l} \[Element] Reals]]
```

is probably as simple as it's going to get

```
E^(-2 I k l) m^2 V^2 + (-I m V + k \[HBar]^2)^2
```

There are a range of functions for dealing with complex numbers and equations: `FullSimplify`, `Simplify`, `TrigToExp` and it's brother `ExpToTrig`, and of course the ever popular `ComplexExpand`, which does such a nice job here. It's worth exploring the help files for these commands because they often give slightly different forms that might be useful in various situations.

As per Kuba's comment... it looks like the assumptions about the particular values being in the reals is not needed in this case... likely this is because ComplexExpand already makes these assumptions.

Comment: Thank you, your comment is helpful!

Comment: Is `{k, V, m, \[HBar], l} \[Element] Reals` needed?

Answer (score 10):

`Simplify` uses as few assumptions as possible when simplifying an expression. This means that it doesn't presume that anything is real, or positive for example. At first this may seem perverse, but in fact it saves **you** from making incorrect assumptions a lot of the time.

`Simplify` is however very adaptable and allows you to not only include your own assumptions as to the variable types you are using, but also what *simple* actually means.

The simplest type of assumption you might want to make is that an elements is in the reals, or that something is within some range.

```
Simplify[somefunction[x,y], {x \[Element] Reals, y>0}]
```

In order to make your own definition of what simple means you can introduce a `ComplexityFunction` argument into `Simplify`. For instance, you can define *simple* to mean that you want to have the fewest possible characters in the expression:

```
f[e_] := StringLength[ToString[InputForm[e]]]
Simplify[Abs[x], x < 0, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

The above is taken directly from the documentation for `ComplexityFunction` but I think it's a good example. The second argument in the above is the assumption.

There are, as @bill s has noted, some ready built commands like `ComplexExpand` which are useful in conjunction with the `Simplify` command.

Another useful tip for using `Simplify` is to note that you can adjust the time for which `Mathematica` will search down a particular transformation path. Setting the option `TimeConstraint->10` will mean that after 10 seconds, it will give up with a particular transformation and try something else. Sometimes you will find that Mathematica makes a large improvement in the simplification of an expression in the first few seconds and then spends a long time making smaller improvements, so the `TimeConstraint` command can be used to define for yourself how long it is spending doing this. The default for this is 300 seconds and of course you can increase this as well if you need to.

You are able also to define your own transformation which `Simplify` will apply to your expression. For instance, you can ask it to use `Reduce`, or `ComplexExpand`. Look up `TransformationFunctions` in the documentation for this.

Comment: Your comment has such a large scope and I need to digest it with further study in mathematica. Thank you very much!